# How to rotate the axis labels in plotly scatterplotmatrix?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-matrix

With plotly express scattermatrix

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df)
fig.show()
```

I would like to rotate the axis-labels (not the tick-labels) of the y-axis, which correspond to the columns in the dataframe, so that they are horizontal. Because, for longer names and more subplots the labels start overlapping pretty quickly. Is that currently doable?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- axis ticks can be rotated.  I cannot find any way to rotate labels
- as a workaround, replace labels and add a key

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df)

# rotate text in yaxes, if text
fig.update_layout(
    {
        f"yaxis{n+1 if n>0 else ''}": {"tickangle": 45}
        for n in range(len(fig.data[0].dimensions))
        if isinstance(fig.data[0].dimensions[n].values[0], str)
    }
)

# get labels of dimensions in splom
labels = [d.label for d in fig.data[0].dimensions]

# replace labels in splom with identifier
fig.update_traces(
    dimensions=[d.update(label=chr(ord("a")+n)) for n, d in enumerate(fig.data[0].dimensions)]
)

# add a key for labels
for n, l in enumerate(labels):
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=(n) / (len(labels)-1),
        y=1.2,
        xref="paper",
        yref="paper",
        text=f"{chr(ord('a')+n)}. {l}",
        align="center",
        showarrow=False,
    )

fig
```

[image]